# How to use textile.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, textile

Well, i've search all around but there are no document neither on google nor on textile.net codeplex, and also no code comment about functionality. So I just want to post a question so that people like me, as well as other people who don't know how to use textile.net will just refer to this article.

How to use Textile.net?

refer answer in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an example I was given:

```
string input = "This _text_ is going to be *formatted* using %{color=#f00;}Textile.NET%.";
string result = TextileFormatter.FormatString(input);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```